# How can AWK be used to list Docker containers?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, docker

I'm looking to use tools along the lines of:

- grep
- sed
- AWK

to work with Docker.

Listing containers:

```
docker container ls | awk '{print $1}'
```

Results:

```
CONTAINER
490e3d669259
a44230a617e1
```

How can I omit the "header"?

Here's the full output for `docker container ls` should that prove useful:

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE  COMMAND                 CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                                        NAMES
490e3d669259  jetty  "/docker-entrypoint.…"  3 minutes ago  Up 3 minutes  0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->8443/tcp  quirky_antonelli
a44230a617e1  jetty  "/docker-entrypoint.…"  4 minutes ago  Up 4 minutes  8080/tcp                                     goofy_hamilton
```

I am just looking for the **values** under the container heading.

Comment: You know that the `-q` flag gives output well suited for further processing?

Comment: yes @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen but it's also to try and learn a bit of awk usage

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With awk, you can skip the first line (or record) using `NR > 1`:

```
docker container ls | awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}'
```

But you don't need that. You can just tell `docker` to [format the output](https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/):

```
% docker container ls --format '{{.ID}}'
bd1299b0dd5a
8fcbcd67a843
```

Comment: This is a good answer since format is really powerful for more complicated cases, but it's worth knowing that for simple cases like this`docker container ls -q` will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The command you're looking for is `tail -n +2`:

```
docker container ls | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n +2
```

Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339483/how-can-i-remove-the-first-line-of-a-text-file-using-bash-sed-script) (there is also an option using `sed` - guess you have to try which is fastest).

Answer (score 1):

Docker gives you more control so that you don't actually need to use a second command piped to do post-processing. In this instance you can just use the `--quiet|-q` option.

```
$ docker container ls -q
490e3d669259
a44230a617e1
```

Many command line tools use similar conventions like `--help` that give more detailed information about usage options. Here is the output of `docker container ls --help`:

```
# docker container ls --help

Usage:  docker container ls [OPTIONS]

List containers

Aliases:
  ls, ps, list

Options:
  -a, --all             Show all containers (default shows just running)
  -f, --filter filter   Filter output based on conditions provided
      --format string   Pretty-print containers using a Go template
  -n, --last int        Show n last created containers (includes all states) (default -1)
  -l, --latest          Show the latest created container (includes all states)
      --no-trunc        Don't truncate output
  -q, --quiet           Only display numeric IDs
  -s, --size            Display total file sizes
```